# Is it possible to undo someone's conversion?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, ger-toshav

If someone converted to judaism via an Institution X, can an institution Y undo the conversion or make a proclamation saying they do not recognize this conversion as a true conversion?

Comment: Only if they think Institution X botched the process.

Comment: Thanks and what is your source?

Comment: They can challenge the mechanics of the conversion, e.g. if they feel Institution X's rabbis are invalid from serving as witnesses or the mikvah or circumcision were invalid. More often they can say "we weren't sure if enough commitment was demanded of the applicant", or "we believe the commitment was a fraud as demonstrated by the following behavior." But no they cannot un-convert someone, they can express their opinion that the first conversion was no good.